# dividing arraylist into multiple arraylists

Tags: java

My program creates an arraylist of 5000 to 60000 records depending on time of day. I want to split it into as many arraylists as possible that each arraylist will have 1000 records. I looked at many examples online and tried a few things but I ran into strange problems. Can you please show me an example of this?

Regards!

Comment: Where is the code that caused you problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public static <T> Collection<Collection<T>> split(Collection<T> bigCollection, int maxBatchSize) {
    Collection<Collection<T>> result = new ArrayList<Collection<T>>();

    ArrayList<T> currentBatch = null;
    for (T t : bigCollection) {
      if (currentBatch == null) {
        currentBatch = new ArrayList<T>();
      } else if (currentBatch.size() >= maxBatchSize) {
        result.add(currentBatch);
        currentBatch = new ArrayList<T>();
      }

      currentBatch.add(t);
    }

    if (currentBatch != null) {
      result.add(currentBatch);
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Here's how we use it (assuming emails an a large ArrayList of email addresses:

```
Collection<Collection<String>> emailBatches = Helper.split(emails, 500);
    for (Collection<String> emailBatch : emailBatches) {
        sendEmails(emailBatch);
        // do something else...
        // and something else ...
    }
}
```

where emailBatch would iterate over the collection like this:

```
private static void sendEmails(Collection<String> emailBatch){
    for(String email: emailBatch){
        // send email code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it works, but how would I extract data from a collection? I've never used collections before.

Comment: You have.  :)  The ArrayList is a collection.  Most likely you'll want to iterate over the collection.  I've added an example usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subList` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList  from `List` to split your `ArrayList`. The sublist will give you a view of the original list. If you really want to create a new list, separate from the old one, you could do something like:

```
int index = 0;
int increment = 1000;
while ( index < bigList.size() ) {
   newLists.add(new ArrayList<Record>(bigList.subList(index,index+increment));
   index += increment;
}
```

Note you'll have to check for off by one errors here. This is just a quick pseudocode sample.

Comment: I think the OP wants 5-60 separate `ArrayList`s containing 1000 records each. Not 5-60 `ArrayList`s that provide different views of the same array of 5000-60000 records.

Comment: That code won't compile. I think you meant `new ArrayList<>(bigList.subList(index, index+increment))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I have now

http://pastebin.com/hEpXikws

but I get the following runtime error

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 29000
 at java.util.SubList.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.RandomAccessSubList.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractList.subList(Unknown Source)
 at proxymanager.Main.main(Main.java:68)